# Eliminate magic number in Redis

Tags: redis, magic-numbers

I'm creating an index with Redis using a sorted set. I want the following order for the matching results (smaller string first):

```
a
ar
art
artu
artur
arturo
```

From the [Redis documentation](http://redis.io/commands/zrevrange) I using a score to store the data:

> The elements are considered to be ordered from the highest to the
>   lowest score.

The code that I write to achieve this has a magic number 1000 but this an arbitrary number, is enough that it's larger than the largest string that I have to store (also I don't know what's the exact maximum string length, but I'm sure that is less than 1000)

```
Hash[
  'elem'  => string
  'score' => 1000 - string.size
]
```

How do you delete this magic number with sense?

Comment: Isn't that lexicographic ordering anyway?

Comment: Descending lexicographical order is used for elements with equal score.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: This is not important to my question, but if you have `tom` and `art` I think that `tom` comes first because I'm using reversed ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the score have to be positive? If not:

```
'score' => -string.size
```

Essentially, this is replacing 1000 with 0. 0 is one of the numbers that you're allowed to use without it being considered magic!

Comment: Good point, seems to works! But this is like a trick, what's happen if not allowed negative number?